# UWP - How to read in a text file?

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am wondering what the best way would be to read in a text file (short text file 5 lines each with names of people) so that data can be selected for a textbox.
I am trying to display the results into a textbox or a list view (or anything better) so that I can then select one of the items to display into a textbox.

I used the StreamReader Class for guidance as shown here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader?view=net-5.0

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("TestFile.txt"))
            {
                string line;
                // Read and display lines from the file until the end of
                // the file is reached.
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(line);
                    TextBox.Text=line;
                }
            }
```

I tried this but only one (the last) line of the text file is shown. Debug.WriteLine(line) shows all lines.

Thanks.

Comment: `listBox.ItemsSource = File.ReadAllLines("TestFile.txt")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ReadLine() read each line.
When you set TextBox.Text=line; text box will show last line.
To show all line in TextBox you will be append each line like

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("TestFile.txt"))
{
    string line;
    // Read and display lines from the file until the end of
    // the file is reached.
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(line);
        TextBox.Text += line;
    }
}
```

For a ListBox:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("TestFile.txt"))
{
    string line;
    // Read and display lines from the file until the end of
    // the file is reached.
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        listBox.Items.Add(line);
    }
}
```

Or a lot simpler:

```
textBox.Text = File.ReadAllText("TestFile.txt");
```

vs

```
listBox.ItemsSource = File.ReadAllLines("TestFile.txt");
```

Comment: Ahh got it. Thank you very much! The File.ReadAllLines is very helpful and simple.

Answer (score 0):

Last line in TextBox is shown because you overwrite it every time in the cycle (Debug.WriteLine will write all the lines in the output, but in textbox, you will see just last line). If you want to see all the lines you can change your code like

```
TextBox.Text += line;
```

The easier way is to use [File.ReadAllText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext?view=net-5.0) method.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense now.